# How to send formatted json to telegram bot using codeigniter?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, telegram-bot

I've form that user will able to add multiple forms. Data from user will be added as JSON string formatted into table column "dataall". Everytime user submit the form, it will trigger simple alert using Telegram bot.

For example my table as below:

```
| id| status | dataall | 
| 1 | Open   | {“0”: {“group”: “A”, “total”: “5”}, “1”: {“group”: “B”, “total”: “7”} } | 
| 2 | Pending| {“0”: {“group”: “B”, “total”: “6”} } |
| 3 | Open   | {“0”: {“group”: “A”, “total”: “5”}, “1”: {“group”: “B”, “total”: “7”} },“2”: {“group”: “C”, “total”: “1”} } |
```

Using Codeigniter, controller will get the data as $result from Database.

Controller:

```
    public function telegram($result)
    {    
    foreach ($result as $data) {
        $status = $data->status;
        $dataall = $data->dataall;
    }


    $json = $dataall;
    $decoded_data = json_decode($json, true);

    $databw;

    foreach ($decoded_data as $each_array) {
        foreach ($each_array as $val){
            $datamsg = $val['group']."|".$val['total'];
        }
    };

    $header = "|Group | Total |";

    $msg = $status."\n\n".$header."\n".$datamsg."\n\n";

    $this->load->model('telegram_m');
    $this->telegram_m->sendmsg($msg);  
    }
```

But using above controller,I'm only able to send 1 array result to the Telegram. For example if the data as below:

```
{“0”: {“group”: “A”, “total”: “5”}, “1”: {“group”: “B”, “total”: “7”} },“2”: {“group”: “C”, “total”: “1”} }
```

Telegram result will look like this:

```
Open

Group | Total
C|1
```

How can I send all the data to the telegram? My desired result, should be like below..

```
Open

Group | Total
A|5
B|7
C|1
```

Thank you for helping.